# Counting the number of even digits in a number?

Tags: c++

I am looking to calculate the even numbers in a given string with C++. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int i(0), c(0), z(0), j(1), n1, x(0);
string n;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello n world!" << endl;
    cin >> n; //The number itself

    while (true)
    {
        if (( n[i] >= '0' && n[i] <= '9'))
        {
            x++;
        }
        else break;
        i++;
    } //Counts the numbers

    cout << "The number has " << x << " digit(s)." << endl;

    istringstream convert(n);
    if ( !(convert >> n1) )
        n1 = 0; //converts string to an int

    while (c < x)
    {
        if ( n1 % 2 == 0 )
        {
            z++;
        };
        n1 = n1 % 10;
        c++;
     }; //Counts the even numbers (I can feel this part is wrong, I just don't know how)

    cout << "The number has" << z << " even digit(s)." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I use it, when I enter 1022, I get 4 even numbers and if I enter 696969 it gives 0 even numbers. What do I do? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This is not a website where you ask people to fix code that does not work.  You should follow the logic of your program, find a part of it that isn't doing what you expect, and ask a question about _that_.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: This code is overly complicated by far. Think about iterating over a string character by character, and using decimal equivalent values from the ASCII table. I can write your `main` legibly in 7 lines, so shoot for under 20.

Answer (score 2):

`n1 = n1/10; not %`

That should solve basic logic to calculate number of even numbers. There could be other errors in code. I don't have C++ on my machine - so can't run it.

Comment: True, but he/she also needs to use % to extract the last digit and check if it is even.

Comment: That is handled (including incrementing the number of even numbers)  in code right before line mentioned above.

Comment: @ChrisD- why?  Think about the definition of even.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop

```
while (c < x)
{
    if ( n1 % 2 == 0 )
    {
        z++;
    };
    n1 = n1 % 10;
    c++;
};
```

after the first iteration variable n1 will be always equal to the last digit of the original number initially stored in n1.

For example if you have number `1022` then after the first iteration due to the statement

```
n1 = n1 % 10;
```

`n1` will be equal to `2`.

And in subsequent iterations n1 will keep this value because

```
2 % 10 == 2
```

In general the logic of the program incorrect. For example if the user enters string `"1022A"` then the expression  in the if statement will be equal to true due to an error

```
istringstream convert(n);
if ( !(convert >> n1) )
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this will be true because "1022A" is not a number 
    n1 = 0; //converts string to an int
```

So there is an inconsistence between the previous loop

```
while (true)
{
if (( n[i] >= '0' && n[i] <= '9'))
{
    x++;
}
else break;
i++;
}
```

that yields `4`  and the second loop where `n1` will be set to `0`.

If to use loops then the program could be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello n world!" << std::endl;

    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s; //The number itself

    unsigned int digits = 0, evens = 0;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size() && s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++ )
    {
        ++digits;
        evens += ( s[i] - '0' ) % 2 == 0;
    }        

    std::cout << "The number has " << digits << " digit(s)." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number has " << evens << " even digit(s)." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Hello n world!
1022A
The number has 4 digit(s).
The number has 3 even digit(s).
```

Or you could check whether a string does not have a valid number representation and in this case issue an error.

Comment: `s[i] % 2`, that assumes that `'0' % 2 == 0`... Better to do `(s[i] - '0') % 2 == 0` (which assumes only that '0'-'9' is consecutive range).

Comment: @Jarod42 I entirely forgot about this.:)